# Formatting date in PHP/MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a PHP/JSON script which uses MySQL and PDO and the data works well now.
Code:

```
 <?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myradio";
$username=test;
$password=test;
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$rows = array();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d%M') FROM mystation");
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '{"success":true,"error":"","data":{"schedule":';
echo json_encode($rows);
echo "]}}";
?>
```

How would I, using the DATE_FORMAT, get my fields start and end (both stored as DATETIME) to appear like this:
16/08/2013 00:00:00

etc?

It *is* displaying the data properly, but I am not quite sure how to get DATE_FORMAT working.

Comment: WHat do you mean with "it is displaying the data properly"?

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? Have you seen this reference? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: Does `DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d/%m/%Y 00:00:00')` sort you out?

Comment: I was trying to get all data in the field start to display like 16/08/2013 00:00:00

Answer (score 4):

Pass the proper format string to `DATE_FORMAT` in your query:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS the_date 
FROM mystation
```

Then the formatted date will be available in a `the_date` column when you loop through your rows.

The following formatting string ,suggested by Marty McVry below, also works:

```
DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d/%m/%Y %T')
```

Reference: [DATE_FORMAT on MySQL manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: As a side note, you can also use `%T` in stead of `%H:%i:%s`

Comment: Thanks, added that to the answer too.

Comment: If there is a mistake in my answer, I'd like to know it, @downvoter

Comment: +1 for the reference to the MySQL documentation, and an example that returns a string in the specified format. But it would also be good to show an example of how to assign an alias to that column in the resultset.  `AS start_dmyt`

Answer (score 0):

Beside the solution bellow, that *is* right: WHEN working with data - in your case passing a date using a REST-API or something - you usually don't want to apply formating. You should return the data AS RAW as possible, to allow the finally processing application to Format data as required.

use the common Format '2013-08-14 20:45:00 GMT+2' ('Year-Month-Day Hour:minute:second timezone') so every Client *is able* to refactor the data retrieved in an appropriate way.

Data should be converted *the Moment* it is presented to the user - no second earlier.

(On the *raw* data Format of a date you can perform `<`, `>`, `equals` comparissions or sorting operations, without doing anything wrong.)

Comment: I'm not so sure that this approach actully insulates one from "doing anything wrong". Handling DATE and DATETIME columns can be complicated, and there are certainly benefits to the approach you describe. But are you certain that this the only appropriate way to handle data? Perhaps you should propose to MySQL that the `DATE_FORMAT` function be deprecated, as a way of helping prevent people from doing things wrong.

Comment: I was trying to get all rows in the field start to have the format like 16/08/2013 00:00:00

Comment: @spencer7593 Doing so would make the interaction between different applications much easier. No, if you are going to Display the data right away, its no Problem formating it inside the query. But when populating the data to external applications, Country/timezone related formations are always bad. Everyone who has ever taken part in an international Project (different timezones, different decimal seperators, different special-chars in strings) will know, what i mean. And since it is - imho - no pain to handle data in a raw Format in very localized applications - why not do so?