# How to convert date in order like dd/MM/YYYY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query selecting table including date field, and I want to convert the date into the format dd/MM/YYYY. I retrieved data like this...

```
$listNews = "
SELECT p.images
     , p.title
     , p.category
     , DATE_FORMAT(p.create_date, '%d/%M/%Y')    
  FROM posts p
 WHERE p.status = 'Active' 
   AND p.category = 'Tin Tức' 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC
";
$stmtNews = $sqlCon->prepare($listNews);
$stmtNews->execute();
$newsPanel = $stmtNews->fetchAll();
$stmtNews->closeCursor();
```

but the result was showing that the variable create_date could not defined, when I take out the DATE_FORMAT It works fine. I do not know where I was wrong. Can you guys help me out that problem.

this is my table structure

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `posts`;
CREATE TABLE `posts`  (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `create_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Active','Unactive') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category` enum('tin-tuc','su-kien','hoat-dong','huong-dan','ho-tro') CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `images` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `images`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `image_code`(`images`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `image_code` FOREIGN KEY (`images`) REFERENCES `uploads` (`code`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 3 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Compact;
```

Comment: Table structure and sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: Just give DATE_FORMAT an alias, so `DATE_FORMAT(p.create_date, '%d/%M/%Y')    create_date`

Comment: I updated a table structure above

Comment: are you make sure that `create_date` have value?

Comment: yes, It's a date value in my table, everything is not null so far.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239687/2943403 regarding how to alias.

Comment: _"the result was showing that the variable create_date could not defined"_ Please show the exact error message.

Answer (score -1):

Using `%m` if you want to output a month as a numeric value.

```
DATE_FORMAT(posts.create_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I tried that one already, but It still had the same error.